# Parsing JSON and adding it to a ListView

Tags: android, json

I have been working on this example for myself for quite sometime and I'm hoping someone can help me as I think i'm very close to the answer! Anyways, what i'm trying to parse is something that looks like [{"fromUser":"Andrew"},{"fromUser":"Jimmy"}], I asked for help before, but I don't feel as if I was as close as I am now. What I am doing is parsing it, then adding it to the list view in a different class. Here is the class that I am currently using. Before this class is called, a post is sent and that is the results (the JSON above)

```
class GetPendingRequests extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private static final String TAG_FROMUSER = "fromUser";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> pendingUsers;
    Context friendsContext;
    ListView friendsList;
    public void setUp(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> pendingUsers, Context context, ListView friendsList)
    {
        this.pendingUsers = pendingUsers;
        this.friendsContext = context;
        this.friendsList = friendsList;
    }
    protected Void doInBackground(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> pendingUsers, JSONArray pendingRequests) {
        HTTPSendPost httpSendPost = new HTTPSendPost();
        String jsonStr = httpSendPost.doInBackground("http://www.brocksportfolio.com/GetPendingRequests.php");

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
               pendingRequests = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_FROMUSER);
                for (int i = 0; i < pendingRequests.length(); i++) {
                    {

                        JSONObject c = pendingRequests.getJSONObject(i);
                        String fromUser = c.getString(TAG_FROMUSER);
                        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        user.put(TAG_FROMUSER, fromUser);
                        pendingUsers.add(user);
                    }
                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        {

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(friendsContext, pendingUsers
                    , R.layout.activity_friends, new String[]{TAG_FROMUSER}, new int[]{
                    R.id.friendslistView});

            friendsList.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that before when I tried, it would crash whenever it gets to the new page. Now what it does it just shows a blank activity and doesn't fill in the listview. Thanks!

Logcat

```
03-17 20:10:46.784 19099-19099/com.skyrealm.brockyy.findmypeepsapp D/Response:﹕ > null 



public class FriendsActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

JSONArray pendingRequests = null;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> pendingUsers;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_friends);
    //DECLARATION
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.friendslistView);
    View friendView = findViewById(R.id.friendsActivity);



   // EXAMPLE:
   // final String latitude = getIntent().getExtras().getString("latitude");
    //On touch swipe listener for swipe right method
    friendView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(FriendsActivity.this) {
        //calls on the swipeRight method
        public void onSwipeRight() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FriendsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
    //end the swipe command
    //send post request
    String htmlUrl = "http://brocksportfolio.com/GetPendingRequests.php";

    HTTPSendPost postSender = new HTTPSendPost();
    postSender.Setup(500, 500, "tesT", htmlUrl);
    postSender.execute();
    //end sending post request

    //create new class object
    GetPendingRequests pendingRequest = new GetPendingRequests();
    //do in background
    pendingRequest.doInBackground(pendingUsers, pendingRequests);

   GetPendingRequests setup = new GetPendingRequests();
    setup.setUp(pendingUsers, FriendsActivity.this, list);
}
```

Comment: So what is your problem? Is it not working?

Comment: I apoligze, let me edit my post, but yes, before I would swipe left and then it would crash. Now when I swipe, I don't get an error, but the activity is just blank.

Comment: Could you please post your error report from Logcat?

Comment: I get no error, it just shows empty, let me show you what logs in my Logcat.
03-17 20:10:46.784  19099-19099/com.skyrealm.brockyy.findmypeepsapp D/Response:﹕ > null

Comment: You mean you can't see a ListView when you run your app?

Comment: What I mean is the ListView in my Activity doesn't get filled in.

Comment: Where do you call setUp() method from? Could you post the other code like ListView's adapter class and more so that I could get better understanding of your implementation.

Comment: Sure @prudhvi i'm very appreciative that you are helping! Give me a moment.

Comment: Let me go through your code. Please give me some time.

Comment: My listviews adapter is in the first code in the onPostExecute method

Comment: @prudhvi no problem, take all the time you need!

Comment: If the app crashes (shows the "Unfortunately" dialog) then there must be a stacktrace in the logcat with the exception. If it doesn't crash, explain what you mean by *crash*.

Comment: I see one mistake you're doing in your application. I'm not sure if this is causing the problem but you should not manually call doInBackground() method. Refer [AysncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) 4th point in 'Threading Rules'. So write all your code in another 'doInBackground' method that is overridden and remove the one you created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's really a lot of bad things in your code. I'll give you few hints:

1) `AsyncTask` should be started with method `.execute()` not `.doInBackgroud()`.

2) You can't pass parameters to method `.doInBackground()` as you've suggested. There is the place where you should specify it -> `AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>`.

3) You've mentioned `Response` is `null`. Are you sure, your `HTTPSendPost` works correctly and really gets data for you? In my opinion not.

4) Passing `ListView`'s reference to `AsyncTask` is really bad pattern. Do not do this. If activity ends and AsyncTask is still running, you'll get `NullPointerException`.

My advice - start [here (`AsyncTask` docu)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and read thoroughly.

Comment: Thank you for all these tips, I'll go change that. Question, when I declare the parameters for AsyncTask, do I put those in the .exectute(); method? Also, I believe my post does work because I have it working for a different class.